# Angular 4 FormArray - Tree Hierachy

Tags: angular, formarray

Does anyone have a working example of a using FormArray with a Hierarchical Tree Structure?

Essentially I am trying to create inline editing for a Hierachy

I can get it to work to the first level, but am stumped how I can get it to call its children recursively

Thanks

Comment: http://www.lidorsystems.com/products/web/studio/samples/angular/treeview/overview or https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overthinking the issue, the answer is a straight recursion routine.  However it can be be a bit fiddly to get going.

I have included a git repo of the answer

https://github.com/swalwellj/FormArray-Tree